# Manual for latest Lubuntu 32bit LTS version

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, documentation

I have an older netbook and after some research decided to try Lubuntu on it.
It's a 32bit unit so the latest Lubuntu LTS version I found was 18.04.
I'm looking for an overall user manual, such as the one currently available for Lubuntu 20.04 64bit here: https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/index.html.
Is there any such thing available?
If not, where could I find all the basic beginner stuff and how-to's?
Thanks

Comment: FYI:   Any Lubuntu/LXDE detail you find that applies to amd64/x86_64 (64-bit) will apply equally to i386/x86 (32-bit).  The Lubuntu manual you reference applied equally to Lubuntu 18.10 & 19.04 using x86/32-bit (both now EOL).  There was no i386/x86 (32-bit) for 19.10 & 20.04 as now only amd64 is offered.

Comment: Also, Lubuntu (modern) is now using LXQt, so anyone using LXDE will be out of step with the Lubuntu Manual

Comment: since Ubuntu is now dropping 32bit support, maybe try Debian instead? they officially suport 32bit (admittedly, the default Debian LXDE environment looks like shit, and it takes a lot of tweaking to make it look as pretty as Lubuntu looks out-of-the-box, though)

Comment: Lubuntu 18.04 is fully supported 3 years from its release, or until 2021-April. The Ubuntu base on which Lubuntu/LXDE is supported for 5 years so until 2023-April (can be extended via ESM for longer but won't include LXDE desktop) My testing of Lubuntu 18.04.5 this month (latest ISO only just came out) included pentium M laptops, pentium 4 desktop, and whilst the two oldest pentium M run much better using GA 4.15 kernel, 32-bit support still currently exists for Ubuntu/Lubuntu. If you need support past mentioned dates, I'd suggest moving to Debian too in the future, but x86 support is dying.

Answer (score 12):

Sorry, but the Lubuntu manual was started for the switch to LXQt which became the official desktop of Lubuntu with Lubuntu 18.10.

On the [Lubuntu links page](https://lubuntu.me/links/) is the [LXDE website](https://wiki.lxde.org/en/Main_Page) or https://github.com/lxde

I'll provide some alternate links, but they're not exactly what you're looking for

- https://wiki.debian.org/LXDE
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LXDE
- https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/LXDE

and of course

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu

and the hundreds of other Lubuntu wiki pages.

You'll note however many of the official Ubuntu pages on LXDE/Lubuntu will have an ***unmaintained and deprecated*** warning (*put there by me*) as the Lubuntu team isn't really updating them anymore. They will mostly apply with Lubuntu 18.04 LTS (*which is why I didn't delete them or have them auto-redirect to lubuntu.me wiki pages though that'll likely be done when Lubuntu 18.04 LTS reaches it's EOL*).

Any (wiki.ubuntu.com Lubuntu pages) I felt no longer applies to Lubuntu 18.04 LTS already auto-directs to lubuntu.me pages (*unless stopped by the reader*) so if a page doesn't re-direct, it was because I felt the information on it was valid and applied to Lubuntu 18.04 LTS (even though I put the *unmaintained and deprecated* warning)

Comment: I'll endeavor to add more as I can, or as I think of them.

Comment: As I recall, the redirection times on the (Lubuntu) wiki.ubuntu.com varied on how useful I though the information was for supported releases (ie. 18.04 LTS). I use other criteria as well (ie. historical information I tend to be a little slower on redirection), but details I though no longer applied to 18.04 had me reduce the auto-direct timing  (if some details on a page were applicable for 18.04, some weren't.. I just made a judgement call).

Comment: It shows as $6.04 for me, amazon tend to offer different prices depending on how you get there, and your detected or known *history*.  On the plus side, it's more of a user guide any link I provided (which tend to be a little technical).

Comment: I would add it as your own answer, I for one will +1 upvote it.  From the sample it reminded me of the Ubuntu Manual project type of manual (and that was last completed for 16.04; https://ubuntu-manual.org/) in being average-user oriented, and if available free to some people it's a great resource. Even at $6.04 it's probably a great buy for many time-scarce users...  It's also probably worth adding to discourse.lubuntu.me (given the 18.04 manual never went public - https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/18-04-manual-on-the-web/231)

Comment: the LXDE wiki is up by the way - https://wiki.lxde.org/en/Main_Page

Comment: You got me downvoted and whined at. So, I removed it rather than cause contention. OP should just use their favorite search engine for "Lubuntu 18.04 User Guide" and click on the results.

Comment: Sorry @KGIII, I didn't anticipate teward's response.